# Search query to return results for which all the items in each result are contained in the query

Tags: mysql, search, logic

I'm building a cocktail machine & using the [Absolut API](https://addb.absolutdrinks.com/docs/drinks) for the ingredients/drinks.

The aim is to select all the ingredients installed in the machine and add them to a DB (this part is already done).

Then I want to query the API to return all the cocktails are able to be made. E.g. if there are 6 ingredients then I want it to return cocktails that can be made with any of these 6 (or less) ingredients.

The trouble is - the API only allows an and operator so searching ingredient1 AND ingredient2 AND ingredient3 etc... will only return results that contains all of these ingredients.

How can I return a list of possible cocktails?

I thought about trying all the combinations but that gets up to 6! queries..

Comment: When I clicked `Absolut API` link in your question, I got: `{"error":"Unable to find the specified file."}`

Comment: Strange - this link right? https://addb.absolutdrinks.com/docs/drinks

Comment: Still doesn't work, however there is one working in a webcache: http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:2sLpT1gwfFQJ:https://addb.absolutdrinks.com/docs/drinks+&cd=1&hl=pl&ct=clnk&gl=pl&lr=lang_en%7Clang_pl

Comment: Weird. I guess it doesn't matter that much - it's more about trying to get this list of cocktails when all I have is an AND operator.

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't seem to be a way of doing this until they produce an `IN` operator.

However, Rather than 6! factorial queries I would suggest querying just 6 times.

Just `drinks/with/ingredient_id/` for the 1st ingredient. Then for the second doing `drinks/with/ingredient_id/not/1,2,3,4` (that is the IDs you got from the 1st query).

Now you got your dataset just check if the ingredients array of each drink doesn't contain something in your list.

Its the only way I see to get even okay performance

Comment: Not sure I understand this - why have you used a not operator?

Comment: Oh... Cause you wouldn't want any drink you've already fetched to be fetched again. So, the second ingredient would query for all that are not already fetched by the first ingredient